# Insert rows into TableView onto without changing scroll position

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I would like to insert new rows into the UITableView above index 0 similar to how iMessage does it when you scroll up and load previous messages.

This is my current implementation:

```
let indexPaths = (0..<newItemsCount).map { IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) }
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.insertRows(at: indexPaths, with: .top)
tableView.endUpdates()
```

this however causes the tableview to make a sudden jump.
This is an example of iMessage

[image]

What I have tried so far:

- Setting the content offset to the original offset before I inserted new rows
- Scroll to cell that was ontop before I inserted new rows, this actually causes a flash of the table view
- reloading data

Comment: try this- tableView.insertRows(at: indexPaths, with: .none)

Comment: Unrelated but `begin-/endUpdates()` is useless for a single insert operation.

Comment: @vadian ah thanks that's good to know....

Comment: @Niv having animation none doesn't help the tableview still jumps

Comment: Can you post your whole controller code. There must be a reload data you forgot about or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you do not need to make beginUpdates/endUpdates/insertRows for the tableView, just insert a new model and reload the tableView that enough.

You can resolve the problem like this:

```
// Calculate the distance of the tableView
// from the current content offset to the end of the content size
let distanceFromOffset = self.tableView.contentSize.height - self.tableView.contentOffset.y

// Insert new model into the list model at zero index
self.messages.insert(message, at: 0)

self.tableView.reloadData() // reload tableView

// Calculate new content offset after reload tableView
let offset = self.tableView.contentSize.height - distanceFromOffset

self.tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
// set new content offset for the tableview without animation
self.tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: offset), animated: false)
```

Comment: works thank you, its not as smooth as iMessage but it does what I asked. Thank you